# Is that possible to share pc speaker among PC over ethernet?

Tags: audio, ethernet

I have few PC in same LAN.  Only one PC has speaker.  I want to play music from another PC but I want the sound to play out on the only PC that only has speaker via LAN.  Is that possible to do so?

Comment: This belongs to superuser.com, doesn't it?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Linux, you could take a look at Pulseaudio. One of its features is the server architecture, will allows to play sound over a network.

Comment: I am using Windows 7.